# NSAnimationContext setCompletionHandler not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, objective-c-blocks

`setCompletionHandler` method from `NSAnimationContext` is not working for me. I am using code form Apple's documentation:

```
    [NSAnimationContext setCompletionHandler:^{
   // This block will be invoked when all of the animations
   //  started below have completed or been cancelled.
    NSLog(@"All done!");
```

And I have the following error: No known class method for selector 'setCompletionHandler:'

When I look into `NSAnimationContext.h` file next to this method there is `#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE` and `NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_7)`. My deployment target is "10.7", however I do not know how can I check if `NSBlocks` are available. Or maybe the problem lies in other thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code in the documentation has an error. The `-setCompletionHandler:` method is an instance method, not a class method. You need to invoke it on `[NSAnimationContext currentContext]`, not on the class itself:

```
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{
   // This block will be invoked when all of the animations
   //  started below have completed or been cancelled.
    NSLog(@"All done!");
}];
```